# VB6 - Dynamically invoke method in referenced DLL

Tags: reflection, dll, vb6, invoke

This question is almost identical to the one here:
[Dynamically invoke a method in DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957141/dynamically-invoke-a-method-in-dll)
Except I need it in VB6. I remember reading somewhere that VB6 supports reflection of ActivX Modules.

I just want to load a valid VB6 DLL, and call a method called "Say", and pass one parameter, "Hello".

Can anyone provide some sample code similar to the sample in the answer of the referenced question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Alex's answer, as commented by Bob.

```
Dim Obj As Object: Set Obj = CreateObject("Prog.Id")
' Just Do It! 
' A runtime error will occur if the object does not have a suitable method. 
Obj.Say("Hello")
```

Comment: So "Prog.Id" would be the path to my DLL? And if so, would CreatObject accept a byte array instead of a path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CallByName`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186143):

```
Dim Obj As Object: Set Obj = CreateObject("Prog.Id")
CallByName Obj, "Say", VbMethod, "Hello"
```

Or the [Typelib Info library](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18589).

Comment: You don't need to use CallByName, just go ahead and invoke the late-bound method as long as you know its name at compile time.

Comment: Where would I place the path to my DLL? In the references?

Comment: In both provided answers I am riddled with,
"Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object"

Comment: The DLL needs to be registered (as admin; regsvr32 "c:\xxx\zzz.dll") then you can use CreateObject to access a ProgID in the dll (ProgID = name of a COM automation object in the dll e.g "MyDLL.SomeClass")